# Blender rigify problems

Tags: animation, rigify

I'm new to blender and am trying to attach rigify to my model, but it is not working. When ever I attach the mess to the rig weird things happen, I can't see all of the mess and my model is all messed up. Also, when I take bind to vertex groups off in the armature modifier the model goes back to normal. But, then i cant animate it! This is what happens:

[image]

Comment: Rigify problems can only be solved with the help of blend file.
Anyway, Before parenting your mesh to armature, make sure that rotation, location and scale is applied to the mesh(Ctrl+A show the menu for it).
Then apply your armature.

Comment: Make sure "Auto Run Python Scripts" is checked in user preferences->file

Comment: violentmonk it didnt work

Comment: I am also having problems with rigify, at the beginning it was working properly, and I have done some animations with my character but after that when I open the same file without making any changes, rigify started to give many problems. It does not animate, it does not move any part of the mesh. I am not sure but after all, blender started to create many problems. I was using Blender 2.68a and then when I realized that 2.69 is exsit, I downloaded and I started to use 2.69 but 2.69 has too many problems when I compare it with 2.68a.